# What is the correct way to get the object instance inside its own method in zval format and update a property with a long value?

Tags: php, c

I'm creating an extension for php in c, but I'm having an error updating a property of type long. I'm trying to use the code below to update the property.

```
zend_update_property_long(kaya_class_entry, getThis(), "lastError", sizeof("lastError") - 1, error);
```

This is my implementation of the method that uses "getThis()" everywhere I use "getThis()" throws an error.

```
PHP_METHOD (Kaya, login) {

    KAYA *ptr = NULL;
    zend_string * username;
    zend_string * password;
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(2, 2)
            Z_PARAM_STR(username)
            Z_PARAM_STR(password)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END();
    zend_resource *kaya;
    zval kaya_ptr;
    int error;

    char *mUsername = ZSTR_VAL(username);
    char *mPassword = ZSTR_VAL(password);

    char *mLicenseDir = licenseDir();
    ptr = fn_kaya_login(mLicenseDir, mUsername, mPassword, &error);
    if (mLicenseDir != NULL) free(mLicenseDir);

    zend_update_property_long(kaya_class_entry, getThis(), "lastError", sizeof("lastError") - 1, error);
    if (ptr == NULL) RETURN_FALSE;

    kaya = zend_register_resource((void *) ptr, le_kaya);
    ZVAL_RES(&kaya_ptr, kaya);
    zend_update_property(kaya_class_entry, getThis(), "resource", sizeof("resource") - 1, &kaya_ptr TSRMLS_CC);
    RETURN_TRUE;
}
```

I'm getting the following error while compiling.

```
In file included from /usr/include/php/20210902/main/php.h:36,
                 from /tmp/tmp.b71QT2xy5G/ext/kaya.c:7:
/tmp/tmp.b71QT2xy5G/ext/kaya.c: In function 'zim_Kaya_login':
/usr/include/php/20210902/Zend/zend_API.h:472:73: warning: passing argument 2 of 'zend_update_property_long' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 #define getThis()       ((Z_TYPE_P(ZEND_THIS) == IS_OBJECT) ? ZEND_THIS : NULL)
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
/tmp/tmp.b71QT2xy5G/ext/kaya.c:138:49: note: in expansion of macro 'getThis'
     zend_update_property_long(kaya_class_entry, getThis(), "lastError", sizeof("lastError") - 1, error);
                                                 ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/php/20210902/Zend/zend_API.h:446:79: note: expected 'zend_object *' {aka 'struct _zend_object *'} but argument is of type 'zval *' {aka 'struct _zval_struct *'}
 oid zend_update_property_long(zend_class_entry *scope, zend_object *object, const char *name, size_t name_length, zend_long value);
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2):

In php 5 you can do it like that

```
custom_object *obj = (custom_object *)zend_object_store_get_object(
    getThis() TSRMLS_CC);
```

[EDIT] For php 7 you can do it like that

```
zend_object *obj = Z_OBJ_P(getThis());
```

Unfortunately i am also stuck on this for php 7 and im doing researches for around 5-6 hours, they changed alot of commands and functionalities for php7 so i think it became impossible though. If its possible, then i am really shocked how bad this stuff is documented, even here on StackOverflow this is the first topic about it in 5 years. Even their official "docs" are not up to date anymore.

Comment: I created a macro: #define THIS_KAYA_OBJECT()    (zend_object*)Z_OBJ_P(getThis()) and remove all references from ZTS (TSRMLS_CC, TSRMLS_C and other) is possible use #define to not remove and has difference when enable the support to cpp PHP_REQUIRE_CXX now my code is work.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to resolve this would be:

You can cast:

```
 (zend_object *) Z_OBJ_P (getThis())
```

Or create a macro, using a cast

```
#define GET_INSTANCE() (zend_object *) Z_OBJ_P (getThis())
```

and remove the "TSRMLS_CC", TSRMLS_CC is a macro to use when ZTS is enabled

```
zend_object *object = GET_INSTANCE();
zend_update_property(kaya_class_entry, object, "resource", sizeof("resource") - 1, &kaya_ptr);
```